# Cannot read property 'current' of null select2.js w knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I am using the select2 into a knockout custom binding. Until some days ago everything worked fine, but now it stopped working giving me this uncaught type error. Many people have my same problem, but i can't figure out what is happening

Here's my html binding

```
<select class="select2" multiple id="domainSelector" data-bind="selectedOptions:subDomains, select2:{placeholder:i18n('SATA-CerDom:alternativeNames'),allowClear:true,tags:names(),closeOnSelect:false,formatSearching:i18n('SATA-CerDom:formatSearching')}" tabindex="-1"></select>
```

And here is my binding

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
        init: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(el, function () {
                $(el).select2('destroy');
            });

            const allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            const select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.select2);

            $(el).select2(select2);
            if ("selectedOptions" in allBindings)
                $(el).val(allBindings.selectedOptions()).trigger('change');
        },
        update: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            const allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

            if ("value" in allBindings && allBindings.value()) {
                if ((allBindings.select2.multiple || el.multiple) && allBindings.value().constructor !== Array) {
                    $(el).val(allBindings.value().split(',')).trigger('change');
                }
                else {
                    $(el).val(allBindings.value()).trigger('change');
                }
            } else if ("selectedOptions" in allBindings) {
                let textAccessor = v => v;
                if ("optionsText" in allBindings) {
                    textAccessor = (value) => {
                        let valueAccessor = i => i;
                        if ("optionsValue" in allBindings)
                            valueAccessor = item => item[allBindings.optionsValue];

                        let items = $.grep(allBindings.options(), e => valueAccessor(e) === value);
                        if (items.length === 0 || items.length > 1)
                            return "UNKNOWN";
                        return items[0][allBindings.optionsText];
                    }
                }
                const converted = [];
                $(el).select2("data", allBindings.selectedOptions().map(v => {
                    return {id: v, text: textAccessor(v)}
                }));
            }
            if("tags" in valueAccessor()){
                $(el).select2();
                const converted = [];
                $(el).select2(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
            }
            $(el).trigger("change");
        }
    };
```

Comment: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3992#issuecomment-254585090

Comment: already did it, it did not solve my problem @RoyJ

Comment: You don't have a `setTimeout` in your code above.

Comment: @RoyJ yeah i know, i've tried that solution inside the if("tags" in ...) but it still gives me that error